# Error in running tez with pig from hue.Is it a config issue or I'm using wrong argument

Tags: apache-pig, hue, apache-tez

I was doing some exploration with pig+tez and found that it works in CLI with the inclusion of  an argument `-x tez` with pig.
However while running it from hue the same should work with a pig argument  `-exectype` tez ,but it failed with following error message.

```
ls: cannot access /data09/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/uszllmd/appcache/application_1434773690325_1939/container_e08_1434773690325_1939_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/lib/slf4j-api-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /data09/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/uszllmd/appcache/application_1434773690325_1939/container_e08_1434773690325_1939_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/lib/commons-lang3-*.jar: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /data09/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/uszllmd/appcache/application_1434773690325_1939/container_e08_1434773690325_1939_01_000002/hive.tar.gz/hive/hcatalog/lib/*hbase-storage-handler-*.jar: No such file or directory
15/08/26 11:05:58 INFO pig.Main: Pig script completed in 193 milliseconds (193 ms)
```

[image]